# Passtools API to set Icon and Logo

Tags: urbanairship.com, passbook

I am exploring the UrbanAirship Passtools API for creating Event Pass.
Event pass has placeholders for Logo and Thumbnail image. 
Is the available way to dynamically update the Thumbnail image for every pass i create?

Comment: Im not sure about the Passtools API, but you certainly can with [PassKit](https://create.passkit.com/activate/?r=1).  The PassKit API is also on [Mashape](https://www.mashape.com/passkit/passkit) so you can experiment with methods via the browser.

Comment: I have already tried this successfully using PassKit. Looks like we need to use paid services to have icon / thumbnail updated dynamically.

Comment: For Passtools or PassKit? PassKit free accounts now have full use of all API methods.